# Why are radio buttons and checkboxes so tiny in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

[image: Tiny radio buttons and checkboxes]

This is a screenshot from Bootstrap in IE9 but this seems to be the default. I don't understand why these controls are so tiny.

In IE6 to IE8 they are much larger and thus more clickable.

Any advice on making them larger using CSS only is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have zoomed in in the screenshot you linked to. Do the check boxes look proportionally correct when the zoom level is 100%?

Comment: No, when I set zoom level to 100% I have the same problem as well. This is using the officially provided VMs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with checkbox. We use bootstrap.css and there is the rule

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It caused to this problem in my case. So I add folowing style to my checkbox and it solved the issue:

```
.my-class input {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize both radio buttons and checkbox's with the help of scale function.

CSS Code:

```
input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox] { 
-ms-transform:scale(2,2);
transform: scale(2, 2); 
-moz-transform: scale(2, 2); 
-webkit-transform: scale(2, 2); 
-o-transform: scale(2, 2); 
}
```

Sample [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpku6d89/19/)

Comment: Tested with IE8... no go.... usual sized, no effect on them. In short, its still not a trusted method... and with browsers like IE... it will still be a few years before we can rely on css3 and so on.

Comment: I am sorry but he says, 'In IE 8 he has no issues '.

Comment: When i tested in a stock standard IE 8, default install on a windows machine. It failed to render them any different. The point more so is that this is not reliable in cross browser support.. Just yet, we're getting closer. You ideally will need an alternative element in place of a input radio/check

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes/Radio Groups... generally fail to resize in cross browser support.. Without playing around with them quickly.. I do recall this was always a pain in the ###..

Personally i would suggest finding a replacement element for them, this is why there are so many packages out there that support graphical versions of them.

While using transform/height/width will work in some cases... You will still end up with certain browsers failing to adjust them. So it could be that your page has a generally larger scale but they fail to scale.

Not ideally a good answer, but this goes from past experiences.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions found so far were working in IE9 here. I finally found mention of the `\ ;` hack and tried it. Presto!

```
/* IE9 */
:root input#my-checkbox {
    width:20px !important \ ;
    height:20px !important \ ;
    box-sizing:content-box !important \ ;
}
```

This may also affect checkboxes in IE8? IE10? but we have separate conditionals for those anyway.